# Type Void is Not Assignable to Type Boolean (React/Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-2016

I'm getting an error where I want to post a switch boolean value on Change. I'm using React/Typescript... What I want to do here send a post request of the boolean value in the handleChange() function, how would I do that?

The current error i'm getting is `Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, checked: boolean) => void) | undefined'`

```
interface IState {
  application?: Map<{}, {}>;
  hasChanged?: boolean;
  checkedA?: boolean;
}



 <div className={classes.switchContainer}>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <FormControlLabel
                      control={
                        <Switch
                          checked={this.state.checkedA}
                          onChange={this.handleChange()}
                          value="checkedA"
                        >Toggle</Switch>
                        }label="YES"
                        />
                  <Typography color="secondary" variant="body1" className={classes.toggleQuestions}>Is the Mentor information complete?</Typography>
                </FormGroup>
              </div>

 @autobind
  private handleChange() {
    console.log("checkedA")
  }
```

Comment: Just a minor sidenote, there is no need to use autobinding annotations (unless it's Angular...). In order to properly bind `this` you can just define your methods as follows `private readonly handleChange = () => {/* do something */};` which will automatically bind `this` in the body of the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try onChange={this.handleChange} instead
Your way, you are *calling* handle change and setting its return value ("void") as the change handler.  Under certain circumstances this might be appropriate, but not in yours.

Comment: got ya that makes perfect sense. how would i then: get the value of said state of the switch input, and send a post request?

Comment: dude its literally in the documentation.... handleChange(event) { console.log(event.target.value); } https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: yeah i'm using typescript so it's a little different from the documentation. but thanks, i'll use this as a reference.